# Custom Youtube Subscribe button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I am working to create something that might be considered slightly unethical...

To avoid the confirmation popup and keep users on my page I want to create a youtube subscribe button that launches a hidden iframe and performs a click event on the `.yt-uix-subscription-button`

I want to perform 
`$('.yt-uix-subscription-button').click();` on the contents of an iframe that loads my youtube channel. Any ideas or is this just a bad idea. My job is specifically being asked for this despite my objections.

Comment: Is this a technical question or an ethical one? I.e. are you stuck with implementation or do you want opinions on whether to do it or not?

Comment: I'm stuck with implementation, despite my objections.

Comment: What's your code so far?  And, furthermore, what url are you trying to embed into an iframe?  I think I can figure out a way of doing it.  The URL could be blocked due to cross-origin.

Comment: I just realized that they frame block any request that isnt related to a youtube embed link... I'm looking into implementing this now via the youtube API.